# iPhone app storyboard resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mobile

I am currently developing a iPhone application, and im stumbeling on something weird.

My application looks just perfect on a iphone 4, but when it comes to when the screen size is getting bigger the app seems to be getting a bit more 'blurry'. Like the keyboard (when the app is opened) is looking more blurry/pixelated.

Is this a common problem with my storyboard or am I doing something wrong with the views them self?

I have Use Size Classes disabled.

Comment: In order to get this fixed you need to use Autolayout. Do you use that or you have prefixed locations for your elements in your storyboard?
Auto layout helps you out by making your view more flexible in order to work for all devices of every resolution.

Comment: @Korpel Yes I am using auto layout on all, i am  doing add auto constraints when i add a new element

Comment: when you add a new element do you define a specific width and height AND you add coordinates that you want to appear on screen cause it's a mistake people do and that messes with your UI when changing devices or even when you rotate the screen

Comment: Yes I give it a specific width, could this be the problem u think?

https://snapr.pw/i/377ac75539.png

Comment: In order for auto layout to work you need to make your height width and coordinates more flexible. For example you can tell that the width is for example 200 and you make the coordinates for x axis to be 0(start) and 400(end). You get the point?